# SVN: Create a branch to reflect a mixed-revision working copy

Tags: svn, branch

I need to create a branch for a working copy that contains mixed revisions of its contents. It is in an environment where files are updated individually from development into production and have, so-to-speak, independent revision lifetimes. To illustrate, let's say I have this `svn status -u` output in my work-dir:

```
M * 10 file1
M * 20 file2
M * 30 file3
Status against revision: 50
```

So I'd like to create a branch for this working copy where I would like each file's base revision in that branch to be the one corresponding to the checked-out revision in my working copy, all the while preserving the local modifications.

Is this possible? If not, what's the best way to create a branch for such a working copy? (Perhaps creating a branch off of the earliest checked-out revision in the working copy?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can always create branch from your WC
2. In your use-case you **must** create branch (by commit) from your WC in order to store all states of all your files "as is"

Comment: Thanks, it was much simpler than I anticipated.